# If $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}X_n$ converges almost surely then so does $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}Y_n$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Reading the book *Probability and Stochastics* of Erhan Çinlar in page 126 he states (paraphrasing a bit) the following:

> Let $(X_n)$ a bounded sequence of independent random variables and suppose that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}X_n$ converges almost surely. Now suppose that $(Y_n)$ is independent of $(X_n)$ and with the same distribution, then $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}Y_n$ also converges almost surely.

This seems to me a completely erroneous assertion, there is no reason to think that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}Y_n$ converges almost sure, otherwise by Skorokhod theorem every sequence of random variables that converges in distribution will also converges almost surely, what is clearly false.

I'm right or there is something that I'm not seeing here?

---

UPDATE: ok, I didn't read carefully the text as the statement seems true as far the set defined by $B:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}:\sum_{n\geqslant 1}x_n\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is measurable in the product $\sigma $-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. Then seeing the sequences $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ as random objects $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ then if both have the same law then clearly we will have that $\Pr [X\in B]=\Pr [Y\in B]=1$.

Comment: What is it meant by “$(X_n)$ a **bounded** series of independent r.v.”? If it means $|X_n|\le C$ uniformly for some constant $C>0$, then I think that statement is true.

Comment: @nejimban yes, it means just that

Comment: I don't understand. Assume $\sum Z_n$ converges in distribution, how do you get from the statement this that it converges a.s.?

Comment: Same remark as @mihaild. By [Kolmogorov's three-series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem), the a.s. convergence of $\sum X_n$ reduces to $\sum_{n\ge1}\mathbb E[X_n]$ and $\sum_{n\ge1}\text{var}(X_n)$ both being convergent, and these depend only on the distributions of the $X_n$'s.

Comment: @nejimban this theorem its not known at this point of the book. Moreover, at this place where the assertion appears its for showing that $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\operatorname{Var}(X_n)<\infty $. Anyway I think that I didn't read carefully the book, see my update in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a theorem by Levy . See thm 7.3.2 in [Sidney Resnick: A Probability Path](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall20/sta711/Refs/Resn2005.pdf) which says that for independent $X_{n}$'s , $S_{n}$ converges almost surely iff $S_{n}$ is almost surely Cauchy iff $S_{n}$ converges in Probability iff $S_{n}$ is  Cauchy in Probability.  The reason I am posting it as an answer because it is long enough and that it does not depend on the boundedness of $X_{n}$'s which allows you to conclude using Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem.

Here by Cauchy in probability , I mean Cauchy in measure. i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$  $P(|S_{n}-S_{m}|>\epsilon)\xrightarrow{m,n\, \to\infty} 0$. i.e. for $\epsilon,\delta >0$ . There exists $N$ such that $m,n\geq N\implies P(|S_{n}-S_{m}|>\epsilon)<\delta$

Let $S_{n}^{X}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ and $S_{n}^{Y}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}$ .

Then $S_{n}$ converges almost surely $\iff$ $S_{n}$ is Cauchy in Probability . So for $\epsilon,\delta>0$ , there exists $N$ such that $$P(|S^{X}_{n}-S^{X}_{m}|>\epsilon)<\delta\\ \iff P(|X_{m+1}+...+X_{n}|>\epsilon)<\delta \iff \\P(|Y_{m+1}+...+Y_{n}|>\epsilon)<\delta\iff P(|S_{n}^{Y}-S_{m}^{Y}|>\epsilon)<\delta$$.

Thus $S_{n}^{X}$ is Cauchy in Probability if and only if $S_{n}^{Y}$ is Cauchy in Probability. And thus by Levy's Theorem $S_{n}^{X}$ converges a.s. if and only if $S_{n}^{Y}$ converges a.s.

Comment: thank you, I will check this theorem

Comment: I just checked that the link that I gave is only to the contents page  lol.  I have updated the link. The book also has a newer reprint under Modern Birkhauser Classics which is also available.